# How to start BIOS with only mouse as input device

Tags: windows, boot, bios

How can I start BIOS with only mouse as an input device.

I have windows xp embedded.

Comment: -1 should we guess which hardware you are using? what are errors you recieve, what are you trying to archieve?

Comment: I am sorry if I haven't been so clear. So I have a mini pc. And I need to enter BIOS to enable Wake-On-Lan feature

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot connect a keyboard?

Comment: I don't have a keyboard. And just need to enable this option. I really don't use keyboard and if I do I have a remote connection on it. But I can't use remote connection on booting into BIOS

Comment: Just get a keyboard and be done with it.

Comment: You need a keyboard to skip keyboard detection done by BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike the installing windows question I helped you with the other day, unless the bios specifically supports using a mouse only, you will need to attach a keyboard to your system and use it temporarily until you have the bios set up.

As a side note, even with bios's that support a mouse you still likely need to press a key on the keyboard to get in to it. If your embedded device only has one port for a mouse or keyboard I would recommend just unhooking the mouse and use it's port for the keyboard until you have everything set up.

---

You say you don't have a keyboard, then how are you typing this question? Just temporally disconnect the keyboard from your computer and use it for the 10 min you need it, then put it back when you are done.

If you need a perminate solution for remote access to the bios you will need to buy a [KVM over IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28iKVM.29)

Comment: Hi Scott! I really like your big answers. Well you know I have this mini-pc next to me. And I have finally made to install Team Viewer on it so I am using it from my laptop. Problem is that this mini-pc has only usb-ports and I don't have keyboard as I have like 3 laptops and none the desktop PC's..I was thinking if there is combination of mouse clicks or something like that.. But then I just need to wait until monday to buy one :( Thank you for the answer